# A calculation involving algebraic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand why the following identity is true. (It appears on p.94 of David Angell's book *Irrationality and Transcendence in Number Theory*.
Here ${\omega}=e^{2{\pi}i/3}$ is the complex cube root of unity, and $A=2^{\frac{1}{3}}$.
$${\frac{1}{a+bA+cA^2}}={\frac{(a+b{\omega}A+c{\omega}^2A^2)(a+b{\omega}^2A+c{\omega}A^2)}{a^3 +2b^3+4c^3-6abc}}.$$
I was thinking that the splitting field of $x^3 -2$ over $\bf{Q}$ is ${\bf Q}(A,\omega)$. It has degree 6. Any automorphism in the Galois group would be determined by the values it attains at $A$ and at $\omega$. As the minimal polynomial of $A$ has as roots $A$, ${\omega}A$, and ${\omega}^2A$, $A$ must map to one of these roots under any automorphism. The three automorphisms we encounter in this identity seem to be the identity automorphism, ${\omega}\mapsto{\omega}$; $A\mapsto{{\omega}A}$, and ${\omega}\mapsto{\omega}$; $A\mapsto{{\omega}^2A}$. I was thinking that if we write $\alpha = a+bA+cA^2$, then this identity states $${\frac{1}{\alpha}}={\frac{N(\alpha)/\alpha}{N(\alpha)}}.$$ This statement (as written) is of course obvious! My problem is I'm not sure how to work out $N(\alpha)$. Isn't it the product obtained by multiplying the values of $\alpha$ at *all* the 6 automorphisms in the Galois group? Verifying this directly is an algebraic nightmare!! Please forgive my very limited knowledge of algebra/algebraic number theory!

Comment: $N_{\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})/\Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)$ is the product of $\sigma(\alpha)$ for $\sigma$ running over the 3 complex embeddings $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})\to \Bbb{C}$, so the LHS denominator times the RHS numerator. It also simplifies to the denominator of the RHS. Not the same as $N_{\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3},e^{2i\pi/3})/\Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)$ which is the product over the 6 complex embeddings $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3},e^{2i\pi/3})\to \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks! I see some daylight. Why do I only use these three automorphisms? Is it because I am seeking the multiplicative inverse of $\alpha$ in ${\bf Q}(2^{1/3})$

Comment: Why not? The 3 complex embeddings $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})\to \Bbb{C}$, that extend to automorphisms of the Galois closure $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3},e^{2i\pi/3})$,  they are not automorphisms of $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$.

Comment: I see.How do I interpret the denominator of the RHS? Sorry to bug you!!

Comment: Either the product over the 3 complex embeddings, or the determinant of the multiplication by $\alpha$ seen as a $\Bbb{Q}$-linear map $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})\to \Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$

Comment: This second interpretation (as a determinant) feels simpler and more direct! Thank you!!

Comment: You seem to have had the mistaken impression that you need to work inside a Galois extension or use field embeddings to define the norm.  That is incorrect: the norm mapping can be defined for all finite extensions of fields. See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf and the last line of page 2 has the norm expression for $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbf Q$. In Section 5 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm2.pdf the nice formula for the norm in a Galois extension is presented, but that is bad to use as a *first* definition of the field norm.

Answer (score 3):

It is nice work with the $\mathbb Q$- automorphisms but the direct elementary calculation is not difficult really. Note that $w+\dfrac1w=w^2+\dfrac{1}{w^2}=-1$ and that $w^2=\dfrac1w$. Then consider $f(x)=cx^2+bx+a$ so we have to verify that
$$a^3 +2b^3+4c^3-6abc=f(A)f(Aw)f\left(\dfrac Aw\right)$$
One has $$f(Aw)f\left(\dfrac Aw\right)=(b^2-ac)A^2+(2c^2-ab)A+a^2-2bc$$ and
$$(cA^2+bA+a)\left[(b^2-ac)A^2+(2c^2-ab)A+a^2-2bc\right]$$ this product is equal to
$$(cb^2-c^2a)A^4+(b^3+2c^3-2abcA^3+(-2c^2b+2c^2b)A^2+(-2cb^2+2c^2a)A+a^3-2abc$$ which, taking into account that $A^3=2$ and $A^4=2A$ gives the verification.